# form does not make the correct query

Tags: laravel-5.5

I want my admin user to be able to approve a jobpost so I defined a method in my jobposts controller like this:

```
public function approved(Request $request, JobPost $jobpost)
{
    //save
    $approved = $jobpost->update([
        'approval'=> $request->input('approved')
        ]);

    if($approved)
    {     $user = auth()->user();
        $jobposts = auth()->user()->JobPosts;
        $company = auth()->user()->company;
       return view('/JobPosts/admin/WaitingJobPosts',[
           'jobposts' => $jobposts,
           'company' => $company,
           'user' => $user,
           'approved'=> $approved
       ]);
    } else{
        var_dump($approved);
    }


}
```

Then I defined a rout for it in my web.php:

```
Route::patch('jobposts/{job_post}/approved', 'JobPostsController@approved')->name('jobposts.approved');
```

and in my view I have defined a form like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('jobposts.approved', ['job_post' => $jobpost])}}">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">تایید</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

it returns  bool(false). so my query does not work. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your `$jobpost` input in your approve method with `$job_post` because you defined it in your route as `{job_post}`.